# Webview bold tag issue with loadDataWithBaseURL

Tags: android

When setting custom font to an html page and loading the html data using loadDataWithBaseURL the bold tag is being ignored. My code is as below:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", "<html><style type=\"text/css\"> @font-face { font-family:\"customFont\"; src:url('file:///android_asset/fonts/customfont.ttf');line-height:45px;font-size:34px;}  body { font-family:'customFont'; }</style><body><b>The legend is back!!</b></body></html>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

My output as seen below:
[image]

When the same content is loaded using loadData as shown below:

```
 webView.loadData("", "<html><style type=\"text/css\"> @font-face { font-family:\"customFont\"; src:url('file:///android_asset/fonts/customfont.ttf');line-height:45px;font-size:34px;}  body { font-family:'customFont'; }</style><body><b>The legend is back!!</b></body></html>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

My output is as seen below:

[image]

Not sure what the possible problem could be. Is there any specific reason for the same.

Comment: Did u got any solution to this. Even i am having same issue.

Comment: tried with loadUrl method, still same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now i solved this by using bold font and specifying the same using css in my html. My css code is as below:

```
@font-face {font-family: MyArialBold;src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/ArialBold.ttf')} b{font-family: ArialFontBold;}.
```

Hope that helps.